# Retain Edge Ordering in DAG Conversion

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to convert an undirected graph into a directed graph such that for each tuple, the first value is a head and the second is a tail in a directed edge.

Initially I thought using `DirectedGraph[G, "Acyclic"]` would straightforwardly solve this, but considering an example with edges `E={{1,2},{2,3},{5,3},{3,4},{4,6}}`, the `{5,3}` edge connects from `3` to `5`.

[image]

I could convert the graph into something like `E={{1,2},{2,4},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6}}`, and imagine an algorithm exists that detects edges with a larger head and relabels the vertices. For example I could locate a bad pair, swap labels to get `{{1,2},{2,5},{3,5},{5,4},{4,6}}` while swapping the vertex coordinates in-step, iterating until a result like `{{1,2},{2,4},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6}}`. But I wonder what simpler and/or alternative methods you might think of.

Comment: Can you show a complete example of what you did? The vertex ordering in your graph probably doesn't correspond to vertex names (as integers).

Comment: To produce the graph above, I used something along the lines of Graph[E, VertexLabels -> {1,...,6}]. Generally what I do is create a graph Graph[E, VertexCoordinates->V] where V is a list of coordinates, and Mathematica treats the i'th coordinate as vertex i.

Answer (score 4):

**If you have an *undirected* graph,** there is no concept of edge direction. This is what "undirected" means. While Mathematica appears to preserve the ordering of edge endpoints in many cases, *I would definitely not rely on this*.  The internal graph representation may change at some point, which may not preserve the endpoint order of undirected edges.  Example:

```
In[190]:= g = Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {3 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2}];

In[191]:= EdgeList[g]
Out[191]= {3 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2}

In[192]:= EdgeList@GraphComputation`ToGraphRepresentation[g, "Sparse"]
Out[192]= {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}
```

**If you have not a graph object, but a list of ordered pairs,** convert them to a directed graph directly:

```
pairs = {{3, 2}, {1, 2}};

Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ pairs]
```

**What does `DirectedGraph[..., "Acyclic"]` do?**  It orients the edges from vertices that appear earlier in the vertex list to vertices which appear later.  For example:

```
In[199]:= 
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {3 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2}];
EdgeList@DirectedGraph[g, "Acyclic"]

Out[200]= {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3}

In[201]:= 
g = Graph[{1, 3, 2}, {3 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2}];
EdgeList@DirectedGraph[g, "Acyclic"]

Out[202]= {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2}
```

Notice that the only difference between the two inputs above is the vertex ordering.

You may be interested in my [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/) package, which has `IGReorderVertices` to easily reorder vertices without losing any edge/vertex attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use: "DirectedEdge":

```
e = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 3}};
l = DirectedEdge @@@ e
Graph[l, VertexLabels -> All]
```

[image]